# Filtering a vcf with a text file of SNP rsIDs

Tags: vcf, snp, bcftools

I have a vcf file containing an ID field with a snps and a list of human SNPs from dbSNP.I want to remove whatever in dbSNP from vcf file. The text file is like this:

```
rs978760828
rs1008829651
rs1052373574
rs1326880612
rs768019142
rs892501864
rs1010989343
rs1489251879
rs1022805358
rs1322538365
```

How to remove the common snps from dbSNP and my vcf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise against using `grep`, `sed`, `awk` for processing vcfs unless you really know what you're doing - there's almost always an easier way using `bcftools`.

`bcftools view -i'ID=@snplist.txt' in.vcf`